# Save column-wise sum of matrix in same matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Eigen::MatrixXd A(3, 3);

    A << 1, 2, 3,
         4, 5, 6,
         7, 8, 9;

    A = A.colwise().sum();

    std::cout << A;

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me "0 0 0" while, when I use a second Eigen::MatrixXd B to save the result of A.colwise().sum() and then print B, everything works fine. So it seems there is something wrong with the new size of A or something similar. What would be the correct way to handle this, without creating a new temporary matrix.

Answer (score 1):

That is an aliasing issue. If you really want to have the result stored in `A` you can write

```
A = A.colwise().sum().eval();
```

But you need to allocate a new object for the result anyway, so there is no real advantage to store the result in `A` instead of storing it into a new object (also, the new object can actually be a `RowVectorXd`)

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/S55r0t